# MySQL stored procedure character encoding

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've been experiencing a rather annoying issue, when inserting data into a MySQL database table, using a stored procedure. The database, made in MySQL Workbench 6.3, has characters in tables defined as utf8, and it works perfectly well, but insertion into the tables by stored procedures, changes the character encoding, leaving wrong characters instead of the correct ones. I've been looking all over for an answer. Hope someone can help. Thanks !

```
delimiter $$

use lfms_browser$$

drop procedure if exists spAddMember$$

create procedure spAddMember 
(
in member varchar(60) character set utf8, 
in city varchar(60) character set utf8
)

begin

insert into Members
(
member,
city
)

    values 
    (
    member,
    city
    )
    ;

end$$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Whatever client you use to call those procedures is not configured to use UTF-8 (or it's configured to use UTF-8 but actually sends other encoding).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Obviously I use MySQL Workbench 6.3, both for creating the database, as well as creating and calling the procedure.